# DBT Redshift - Target Schema is not used when materializing view with no schema binding option

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbt

Please find the project structure.

profiles.yml

```
redshift_learn:
  outputs:
    dev:
      dbname: dev
      host: 
      user: 
      password: 
      port: 5439
      schema: public
      threads: 4
      type: redshift
  target: dev
```

Project Structure

[image]

dbt_project.yml

```
models:
  redshift_learn:
    stg:
      +materialized: table
```

sources.yml

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: cass_prepared
    database: dev
    schema: dbtinput
    tables:
      - name: people
        identifier: people
```

stg_people.sql

```
{{ config(materialized='view', bind=False) }}

with src_people AS  (
select * from {{ source('cass_prepared', 'people') }}
)
select
*
from src_people
```

I expect the view to be created in public schema. But the view is getting created in dbtinput schema. The run is failing as dbtinput is an external schema.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that is what is happening. Can you share the compiled model code at `target/run/redshift_learn/models/stg/stg_people.sql`? That should include the `create view` statement. If you are selecting from a source that is an external table, you may require some additional config.

Comment: yes.  Adding the package dbt-labs/dbt_external_tables and configuring the sources.yml according to the documentation resolved the issue. The views are now getting created in the target schema.